# Headers (.h) problems with ESP8266 in Arduino

Tags: arduino, libraries, esp8266

I am developing a project where the board is supposed collect data and use ESP8266 to transmit it to a server.

I am getting stuck in what I thought would be the easiest part: using the ESP8266.

There's a lot in the internet about how to use it and which library to download, and it should work perfectly in my computer, with my board.

I must include the ESP8266WiFi.h library, which I may find in a specific repository in GitHub. But my problem is elementar: headers.

I mean, if I include ESP8266WiFi.h it calls another header that calls another and there it goes. But in that "calling-recalling" game, Arduino's IDE finds a lot of unavailable headers.

I've tried to include a lot of them, changing the way the code called the .h codes (between " " instead of < >), or even downloading it directly from internet. There's a incredibly high number of headers missing, almost impossible to cover manually.

Does anyone know a way of doing it faster or differently? May I search/install a different library? If it's right or wrong, how may I code it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you have selected in the **Tools > Board** menu?

Comment: Arduino Genuino/UNO (the one I'm using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP8266WiFi library is part of the [ESP8266 core for Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino). That core and the ESP8266WiFi library are used when you are directly programming the ESP8266. You will have no chance of ever getting the library to compile for the Arduino/Genuino Uno, which uses a microcontroller with a different architecture. You can't just grab a library out of the ESP8266 core for Arduino. It's part of an entire hardware package.

If you're intending to directly program the ESP8266, not an Arduino/Genuino Uno, then you need to [install](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/#installing-with-boards-manager) the ESP8266 core for Arduino and then select an ESP8266 board from the **Tools > Board** menu.

I suspect what you're actually trying to do is to program an Uno, which is using an ESP8266 only as a WiFi module. In this case you will not be able to use the ESP8266 core for Arduino or the ESP8266WiFi library. If you have the AT firmware on your ESP8266 (which is what they typically ship with) then my recommendation is to use this library:

https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to program an Uno.

Basically, sensors of the board collect data and I'd use the ESP8266 as a WiFi module to send these data to a .php file on a certain server